# ArrayList trimtosize not working android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Am having an arraylist and its code is:

```
ArrayList<String> recentdata=new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to limit the size of `ArrayList` to a specific size i.e. 5 in my case, when it reaches to that number.
That means 0 to 5 it works as `ArrayList`, when it reaches to that 5, I want to stop the growth of `ArrayList`.

For that am using: to set the size

```
if(recentdata.size() >= 5) {
    recentdata.trimToSize();
}
```

but its not working i.e., size growth is not stopping it goes 6,7 etc.

How to do this? anyother way to do this? or what is wrong in my approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trimToSize` doesn't remove any element from the list. From [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29):

> Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current
>   size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of
>   an ArrayList instance.

The capacity is the size of the array used by the `ArrayList` internally. If your list contains 6 elements and has a capacity of 10, the last 4 elements of the array are null. Calling `trimToSize` will just make the list use an array of 6 instead of 10.

Just don't add anything to the list once its size is 5, instead of adding, and then trying to remove.

Comment: The thing isi want recent search list for that i have to add recentdata everytime but it is limited to show 5..

Comment: void addRecentSearch(String s) {if (list.size() < 5) {list.add(s);} else {// too bad}}

Comment: Its easy thing i figured it out  but i messed up with that method.. anyway thanx

Answer (score 7):

Size and capacity are two different things.

Say you have this:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(5);
```

Your capacity is 5, but the size is 0.

Then you add some data:

```
data.add("hello");
```

Then you call trimToSize:

```
data.trimToSize();
```

Your size and capacity are both now 1.

What exactly are you trying to do? There is probably a better way to do it :)